# c++11 timed_mutex behaves different from mutex when calling "try_lock_for"

Tags: c++, locking, mutex, atomic

I was expecting that if timed_mutex.try_lock_for could success for all calling threads, like this:

```
timed_mutex tm;
atomic<int> atTm(0);
void tTMutex(int i) {
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::microseconds(200 * i));
    if (tm.try_lock_for(chrono::milliseconds(200 * i))) {
        atTm.fetch_add(1);
    }
}

int main() {
    thread t[3];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size(t); ++i) {
        t[i] = thread(tTMutex, i);
    }
    ready = true;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size(t); ++i) {
        t[i].join(); // seems only 1 thread increased atTm
    }
    cout << atTm;
    return 0;
}
```

It prints "1", while I expected that it could print "3". As long as 3 threads call `tm.try_lock_for` in different time, I think they should all successfully return, but in fact not: what's the reason for this?

I changed my program slightly, using ordinary `mutex` instead of `timed_mutex`, as below:

```
mutex mAllWait; // change 1
atomic<int> atAll(0);
void tMutex() {
    unique_lock<mutex> lk(mAllWait); // change 2
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(200));
    atAll.fetch_add(1);
}

int main() {
    thread t[3];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size(t); ++i) {
        t[i] = thread(tMutex);
    }
    ready = true;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size(t); ++i) {
        t[i].join(); // all threads can increase atAll
    }
    cout << atAll;
    return 0;
}
```

It prints `3`, as I expected. So what's the core difference between the 2 programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not unlocking the mutex after acquiring the lock in the first version:

```
if (tm.try_lock_for(chrono::milliseconds(200 * i))) {
    atTm.fetch_add(1);
    tm.unlock(); // missing
}
```

so only the first thread will be able to ever acquire it. That's why `std::unique_lock` should be preferred. It unlocks in its destructor. It also accepts `std::timed_mutex` as template argument and has the `try_lock_for` member function has well.

---

That aside:

There is no guarantee that `try_lock_for` will wait as long as you specified. It may wake up spuriously before the time limit is reached and return `false`.

That could happen immediately when you start waiting or at any other time before the mutex can be acquired or even if the mutex is currently not acquired by any other thread. Then you don't increment `atTm` in that thread.

Of course there is also the possibility that the `try_lock_for` calls actually do time out and you wont increment for that reason, but I assume as long as you don't run this on a heavy overloaded system that shouldn't happen.

Run the `try_lock_for` call in a loop and check whether the time has actually exceeded if you care about that. This is probably simpler to do with `try_lock_until`.

Comment: Presumably in real use cases, if you have other work you could be doing while waiting for the lock, you'd just try once and then do something else for a short while, without spending extra CPU time to detect spurious early bailout from `try_lock_for`.  But yes that sounds like good advice for an experiment like this to investigate how it operates.